# Determine whether a user has opened a database already

Tags: lotus-notes

The database is not new, adding profile documents, environment variables, etc... won't help.
Here's what I need: When a user opens the database, there will be a `dialogbox` popping up (or not), based on the information whether it's the user's first time opening the database or not.

Comment: Is using database's "About Document" an option? It would show up only to those users which haven't openened the database yet.

Comment: @Knut Herrmann This would have been my last resort option, I will use that if there's no other choice left.
I figured since the "About Document" is somehow getting first time users (probably from whether there's an existing bookmark for the database) I might be able to do the same thing. Looks like I'm wrong...

Answer (score 0):

You have to do this yourself, using `profile documents`, `environment variables` or something else. In my opinion there is no `lotus notes` `api` support available!